# Functional testing angular

Tags: protractor

I am required to functional test a web app built using angular 5. The app has a lot of chart widgets - basically reporting done through the chart based on the values in the sql server database for specific criteria given through the query bar. I basically have to check for dynamic changes in the charts based on updates - add/delete/change in the database. There are several different charts which get affected by those changes and I have to validate both the ui and db using automation. I have been reading that protractor can be used for e2e testing, would I be able to validate data updates and changes to the chart using protractor or please suggest me a tool for this. Also I am not seeing a lot of blogs for checking dynamically generated charts using protractor. Please help me with any material you can.

Answer (score 0):

Could be really difficult to do using protractor if we are talking about a production-like environment, with dynamic data. Develop such an e2e test like the case that you are describing will, at the best case, provide you a flaky test that will provide you a large quantity of fake-failings.

If you are using a library to generate the charts like Highcharts, i would divide the testing on two pieces:

A) The easier part: Check that the endpoints that need to provide the data to the charts are retrieving properly the data comparing it to the present data on the DB. You could use a module like protractor-intercept ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-intercept ) to easily handle that. With these, you will be testing that the data arrives properly from the DB to Client.

B) Difficult part: Mock the data retrieved for those endpoints on a test environment ( yes, you will need help from development team).  If you know the data that you are expecting, will be easier to assure that is being properly rendered on the front-end charts.

Those kind of tests are hard to deal. A months ago, I had to design one of those and finally the team decided to cover only the api responses, instead of all the e2e flow.